Using a container inside a custom comparator for comparison
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> wordsContainer={"aba", "baba","ris", "u"};
    auto cmp=[&](int i, int j){
        if (wordsContainer[i].size() != wordsContainer[j].size())
            return wordsContainer[i].size() < wordsContainer[j].size();
        return i < j;
    };
    std::unordered_map<int,std::set<int,decltype(cmp)>>mp;
    mp[0].insert(2);  // <-- this line is the issue
}

I'm trying to do something like this, in C++20. I wanted my container be sorted based on some other container. But compiler complains about the type of cmp, removing & from [&] works but then I don't have access to variable wordsContainer.
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/map:60,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/stdc++.h:81,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Rb_tree_key_compare<_Key_compare>::_Rb_tree_key_compare() [with _Key_compare = main()::<lambda(int, int)>]’:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_tree.h:688:22:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Rb_tree_impl<_Key_compare, <anonymous> >::_Rb_tree_impl() [with _Key_compare = main()::<lambda(int, int)>; bool <anonymous> = false; _Key = int; _Val = int; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<int>; _Compare = main()::<lambda(int, int)>; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_tree.h:935:7:   required from ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> >]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/tuple:1678:63:   required from ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> >]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_construct.h:97:14:   required from ‘constexpr decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) std::construct_at(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) = std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >*]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/alloc_traits.h:514:4:   required from ‘static constexpr void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > > >]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_tree.h:618:32:   required from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_construct_node(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >*]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_tree.h:635:21:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >*]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_tree.h:2461:33:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_hint_unique(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > > >::iterator; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > > >::const_iterator]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:520:37:   required from ‘std::__cxx1998::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::__cxx1998::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::__cxx1998::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> > > >; std::__cxx1998::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::__debug::set<int, main()::<lambda(int, int)> >; std::__cxx1998::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’
main.cpp:339:9:   required from here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_tree.h:149:24: error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda(int, int)>::<lambda>()’
  149 |       : _M_key_compare()
      |                        ^
main.cpp:333:16: note: a lambda closure type has a deleted default constructor
  333 |     auto cmp=[&](int i, int j){
      |                ^


compiler option:

-std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wfloat-equal -Wduplicated-cond -Wlogical-op -Wall -Wextra -O2 -Wlogical-op -Wshift-overflow -Wduplicated-cond -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-sanitize-recover -fstack-protector

I also tried std::unordered_map<int,std::set<int,cmp>>mp; but it gave:
main.cpp:338:21: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Key, class _Cmp, class _Allocator> class std::__debug::set’
  338 |     map<int,set<int,cmp>>mp;
      |                     ^~~
main.cpp:338:21: note:   expected a type, got ‘cmp’
main.cpp:338:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  338 |     map<int,set<int,cmp>>mp;
      |                        ^~
main.cpp:338:24: error: template argument 4 is invalid
main.cpp:339:7: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
  339 |     mp[0].insert(2);

Is there a way to achieve this? I looked into this but it didn't helped.

Old deleted question: Using a container inside a custom comparator

yes, that is old deleted question

It would have been better to edit the question and have it reopened. That said, you have changed almost nothing about your question since asking the first time. And that one was closed.

You need to pass cmp to the set – there is no way to create an instance of decltype(cmp). See constructor 2 here.

@molbdnilo I tried that too, but it still gave error, I've updated my question with it.

Now that I think about, that's not going to work. The problem is that a capturing lambda has no default constructor, so you can't use operator[] on the map.

Do you have any solution in mind for this?

What is the underlying logic you are trying to implement? Your comparator looks buggy, e.g. what will happen if you do insert(4)?

@pptaszni Just because the comparator cannot handle certain values does not make it automatically buggy. Just don't ask it to operator on unsupported values.

@pptaszni It's not buggy and is part of a larger code that makes sure that I'll be inserting values within the range of wordsContainer's length. [0,n)

You cannot use operator[] of your map, because it needs to default-construct your set. And you cannot default-construct std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> mySet;, because your cannot default-construct an instance of your capturing lambda.
Instead of operator[] you can use insert:
mp.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::set<int, decltype(cmp)>{cmp}));
mp.at(0).insert(2);

Note however that the logic of your comparator might be broken, e.g. it will cause Undefined Behavior if you insert an element that is bigger/equal to the size of your wordsContainer.

Thanks, when i use std::unordered_map<int,std::set<int,cmp>>mp; instead of std::unordered_map<int,std::set<int,decltype(cmp)>>mp; any idea why it doesn't work? In the link attached it said C++20 allows that and I'm unable to find out the problem. It says error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type.
Also, why is {cmp} required while inserting? Isn't it the old standard using like this std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp); and in C++20 we have std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> s;

Can be either {cmp} or (cmp). But you cannot use the first overload of set constructor, because it will try to default-construct the comparator, which is not default-constructible. So you need to use second overload where you pass comparator as an argument.

I have never heard about possibility to use std::set<int,cmp> if the cmp is a lambda. Do you have some links to the documentation about it?

Ah, I misquoted the std::set<int,cmp> part, my bad.

I'm little confused about the default constructor part, how in std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> s; it is able to initialize set s?

You cannot use std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> s; if cmp is not default-constructible (e.g. it is a capturing lambda). That's why we use std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> s{cmp};

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
